# Need to deploy SSL self signed certificate on HP 5500 EI L3 switch

Tags: switch, hp

I have HP EI 5500 L3 switch, I am trying to start HTTPS on switch but it give me error

`Error: Failed to enable HTTPS server.`

This might be because of SSL certificate was not there on switch.

Can anyone help me on this.??

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what version of Comware you are using, you might need to use a CA Server rather than a generated selfsigned certificate.

Early versions of Comware 3 and 5 seem to need a CA while later versions of Comware 5 and Comware version 7 can use a self signed certificate.

Looking at the configuration guide for the 5500 it states the following:

> Enabling the HTTPS service triggers an 
>   SSL handshake negotiation process. 
>   During the process, if the local certificate 
>   of the device exists, the SSL negotiation 
>   succeeds, and the HTTPS service can be 
>   started properly. If no local certificate 
>   exists, a certificate application process 
>   will be triggered by the SSL negotiation. 
>   Because the application process takes 
>   much time, the SSL negotiation often fails 
>   and the HTTPS service cannot be started 
>   normally. In that case, execute the 
>   ip 
>   https enable 
>   command multiple times to 
>   start the HTTPS service.

So if the negotiation does not start which gives you your error, trying using the **ip https enable** multiple times to start the service and begin the certification application process.

You can view the state of HTTPS using **display ip https**

You can find more information using the HP 5500 configuration guide which you can find the link to [here (PDF document)](http://h17007.www1.hp.com/device_help/H3C-Manuals/5500/5500-Configuration-Guide%28R2215%29.pdf)

If you need to configure https with a CA server, you can find the complex set of steps to do this [here](http://hpnetworkers.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/hp-series-h3c-comware-https-howto-with.html)

Hope this helps you on your quest.

SleepyMan